# Get name of gradle module, and the name of any other modules it depends on

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Let's say I have a multi-module gradle project with two gradle modules, `:A` and `:B`.

```
.
├── :A
│   └── build.gradle
├── :B
│   └── build.gradle
├── build.gradle     (plugin applied here)
└── settings.gradle
```

- `:A` has no dependencies
- `:B` has a dependency on `:A`

I want to get the following information.

- a list of the names of each module in project: `:A`, `:B`
- list of module names that each module is dependant on. For `:A`, this would be an empty list, and for `:B` it would be `listOf(":A")` (single element list)

How can I get this information in the context of a custom gradle plugin that's applied to the root gradle module?

The use case for this is to generate a visual representation of how each module is connected in a multi-module project

Comment: You mean `A` and `B` and projects in multi-module project or multi-module projects themselves?

Comment: @Opal multi-module project (standard android project setup) I believe

Comment: Could you just sketch the structure along with relevant `*.gradle` files? Simple ASCII tree will be sufficient.

Comment: added, see edit

Comment: Oops.. ;) No `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: @Opal haha good catch - fixed!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a snippet for going through each `Configuration` and getting the `ProjectDependency` types from them. It uses [`Gradle.projectsEvaluated(org.gradle.api.Action)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#projectsEvaluated(org.gradle.api.Action)) which executes after all the projects are evaluated. It doesn't do anything to figure out transitives or keep a notion of who depends on who, but this can hopefully give you a starting point for how you might achieve what you are looking for.

```groovy
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  println('Projects loaded')
  println('*' * 15)
  allprojects.forEach { proj ->
    final List<ProjectDependency> projectDependencies = proj.configurations.collectMany { Configuration configuration ->
      configuration.allDependencies
    }.findAll { Dependency dependency ->
      dependency instanceof ProjectDependency
    }.collect {
      it as ProjectDependency
    }.unique().collect()
    println("Project ${proj.name}")
    println(projectDependencies.collect { "  ${it.name} -> ${it.dependencyProject.path}" }.join(System.lineSeparator()))
    println()
  }
}
```

I tried it out on the [junit-team/junit5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5) repository and got the following output:

```
Projects loaded
***************
Project junit5


Project documentation
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-jupiter-params -> :junit-jupiter-params
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-vintage-engine -> :junit-vintage-engine
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine

Project junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-commons -> :junit-platform-commons

Project junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console

Project junit-jupiter-migrationsupport
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console

Project junit-jupiter-params
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console

Project junit-platform-commons


Project junit-platform-console
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher

Project junit-platform-console-standalone
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-jupiter-params -> :junit-jupiter-params
  junit-vintage-engine -> :junit-vintage-engine
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-jupiter-params -> :junit-jupiter-params

Project junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-commons -> :junit-platform-commons

Project junit-platform-gradle-plugin
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine

Project junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine

Project junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-platform-suite-api -> :junit-platform-suite-api

Project junit-platform-suite-api
  junit-platform-commons -> :junit-platform-commons

Project junit-platform-surefire-provider
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console

Project junit-vintage-engine
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine

Project platform-tests
  junit-platform-commons -> :junit-platform-commons
  junit-platform-console -> :junit-platform-console
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-platform-launcher -> :junit-platform-launcher
  junit-jupiter-api -> :junit-jupiter-api
  junit-jupiter-params -> :junit-jupiter-params
  junit-platform-runner -> :junit-platform-runner
  junit-platform-engine -> :junit-platform-engine
  junit-jupiter-engine -> :junit-jupiter-engine
  junit-vintage-engine -> :junit-vintage-engine
  junit-jupiter-migrationsupport -> :junit-jupiter-migrationsupport
  junit-platform-gradle-plugin -> :junit-platform-gradle-plugin
  junit-platform-surefire-provider -> :junit-platform-surefire-provider
```

Comment: That's pretty good, however remember gradl'es internal API is used in this code.

Comment: @Opal I don't think I used any internal APIs (as far as I can tell).

Comment: You're right! I thought that `ProjectDependency` is from internal API. Cool! :)

Comment: My project's dependencies (Android) are `DefaultDependencySet`, not `ProjectDependency`. hmm..